# Telnet error - "Connection timed out"

Tags: linux, smtp, telnet, port

I am trying to telnet a port at a client's location.

```
telnet someexampledomain.com 25
```

It shows:

```
Trying someexampledomain.com...
telnet: connect to address someexampledomain.com: Connection timed out
```

- How to diagnose where is the issue and resolve it?
- How to check if this domain and port combination is blocked *internally on the requesting machine* or *the destination/client* is blocking this telnet request?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to test SMTP server and port being used is 25.

Comment: Then traceroute the TCP port and see where it fails. By the looks you have a firewall problem.